# decorators and parameters check inside a python class

Tags: python, class, input, instance, decorator

A class:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

An instantiation:

```
from Spam import *
c = Spam(1,5,4)
```

In this case, to perform a check on the input values of 'a' or 'b' or 'c' I've the decorators @property, @a.setter, @b.setter, @c.setter but...what if I need to check this variables but they are not directly copied into 'private' class variables?

I mean

```
class Egg()
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.var = (a + b)*c
```

Say I need to check a < c and c > b, what is the best way to perform checks on variables 'a', 'b', 'c' inside the class Egg and bound their value to some standards if checks are not consistent? Is there any particular decorator? (I need to keep code "clean and easy to uderstand" outside the class...this is why I am not performing checks before instantiation).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. You cannot use `self.a` as a simple attribute *and* have a `property` object named `a` on the class; the latter would always win as data descriptors trump instance attributes. You'd generally use instance attributes starting with an underscore in that case, so `self._a` for the `a` property, etc.

Comment: If you need to validate arguments to the `__init__` method, then just validate those arguments *right there*.

Comment: Last but not least, you seem to equate *decorator* with *property* here. You can create `property` objects by using it as a decorator, but you don't *have* to.

Comment: You could use custom decorators added to the `__init__` method to add argument validation, but I usually prefer simple and limited validation in the `__init__` itself as that documents what you are doing better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered immutability?

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Egg(namedtuple('Egg', 'a b c'))
    def __new__(cls, a, b, c):
        assert a < c and c > b
        return super(Egg, cls).__new__(a, b, c)

    @property
    def var(self):
        return (a + b)*c
```